# evaluate an integral given unknown function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to evaluate
$$
\int_0^1 (x-2)f''(x) dx
$$
given

```
x = 0 1 2
f(x) = 1 2 -1 
f'(x) = 2 0 1
```

I've never seen such thing before , where $f''$ isn't well defined . I tried calculating

```
x = 0 1 
f''(x) = -2 1
```

and made a guess
$$
\int_0^1 (x-2)f''(x) dx \approx \int_0^1 (x-2)(-2(1-x)+x) dx = 1
$$
but the given answer is $\int_0^1 (x-2)f''(x) dx = 3$ . What should I do , I don't recall learning this in my calculus 1 and 2 before ?

Comment: Try integrating by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can evaluate the integral by integration by parts as below:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1(x-2) f^{\prime \prime}(x) d x&=\int_0^1(x-2) d\left(f^{\prime}(x)\right) \\
&=\left[(x-2) f^{\prime}(x)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1 f^{\prime}(x) d x \\
&=-f^{\prime}(1)+2 f^{\prime}(0)-[f(x)]_0^1 \\
&=0+2 \cdot 2-(2-1) \\
&=3
\end{aligned}
$$